# Какие знаки можно поставить и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

Запятая, тире, двоеточие? Все, один или два? Почему? Только мне нужно знать, какие знаки ВОЗМОЖНЫ, а не какие ЛУЧШЕ.

`— И как же теперь общаться?`

`— Как раньше —/:/, с помощью слов и жестов.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *— **Как рАньше:** /// с помощью слов и жЕстов.*

(2) *— **Как рАньше —** // с помощью слов и жестов.*

(3) *— **Как раньше,** / с помощью слов и жЕстов.*

1. Диалог, предложение неполное. Это БСП, отношения **пояснительные**.
   В общем случае обозначаются **любым знаком:** двоеточие, тире, запятая.

Это соответствует правилам, **выбор** возможен. При этом надо **учитывать** контекст, а также расстановку пауз и ударений.

2. **Двоеточие** — это основной вариант для **пояснительных** отношений, для него характерно интонационное **предупреждение** (понижение голоса перед подчеркнутой паузой).

**Тире** присоединительное, пауза будет **меньше**.

При выборе **запятой**, пауза становится **произносительной,** а первая часть сближается по интонации с вводным сочетанием.

3. В данном случае **запятая** представляется **наилучшим** вариантом по семантике и интонации, так как **основное** содержание обозначено во второй части.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Лично я полностью согласен с вами, мне тоже кажется запятая лучшим вариантом.

Comment: Мы в чем-то похожи с вами...)